# How can i show image in my html file that's hosted on heroku?

Tags: html, heroku

Hi everyone reading this.

So to summarize, I'm trying to create a webpage for my heroku app, but when I try to add images on it, they won't print. So far my files are organized this way:

Main File

- index.js
- Front

  - adding.html
  - pic.png

Of course names are not exactly those, but you get the point

The way i call them in my html file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hub2Boond - Ajout d'utilisateur
        </title>
         
        <!-- templates -->
        <style>
            .bgQueriadis {
                background-color: rgb(129,192,240);
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 150px;
                left: 40%;
                width: 450px;
                bottom:50px;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
            .logoQueriadis {
                background-color: rgb(54,80,100);
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0%;
                left: 0%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
            .logoAPI {
                background-color: rgb(54,80,100);
                width: 400px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0%;
                left:0%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 150px;
            }
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logoAPI">
            <p><br>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
            <img src="./HubSpot_LogoWBG.png" alt="Logo Hubspot" height="76px" style="margin: auto;">
            <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/0/248.png" alt="pretty arrow" height="76px" style="margin: auto;">
            <img src="./BoondTR.png" alt="LogoBoondManager" height="76px" style="margin: auto;">
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="bgQueriadis">
            <br><br>
            <p style="margin: auto; width: 400px;font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;font-size: 40px;">Informations enregistrées avec succès, vous pouvez quitter la page!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="logoQueriadis">
            <p style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif; color:white;">By Queriadis Consulting &nbsp<img src="./a2f8383a-a348-4d95-a059-3ae2fb574171.png" alt="Logo Queriadis" height="20px" style="margin: auto;">
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know it's poorly coded, I'm still a beginner, but any help, idea or correction is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code is slightly unclear, but there are a few things I suggest.
First, I suggest not using local images (ones stored on your computer), and instead use ones that already exist on the internet. In my experience, having a local image on a public or semi-public site can cause issues. Second, inside the quotation marks where you are assigning the image height, you don't need the px after the number. For example:

```
  height = "76"  NOT height = "76px"
```

There are more resources on beginner image formatting here: [https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp#:~:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,HTML%20Images%20Syntax,-The%20HTML%20%3Cimg](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,HTML%20Images%20Syntax,-The%20HTML%20%3Cimg)